# Random array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So i have this array:

```
var musicQuiz = [
  {
    lyrics: "Now the drugs don´t work",
    answers: [
      "The Verve",
      "Oasis",
      "Adele",
      "Rolling Stones",
      "Chris de Burgh",
      "Ceasars"
    ]
  },
  {
    lyrics: "Go your own way",
    answers: [
      "The Chemical Brothers",
      "U2",
      "The Doors",
      "Fleetwood Mac",
      "Moloko",
      "The Beatles"
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to show the "lyrics" randomly.so I have this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < musicQuiz.length; i++) {
  var question = document.getElementById("question");
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * musicQuiz[i].lyrics.length);
  question.textContent = musicQuiz[i].lyrics[random];
}
```

But it's not working, it only shows a letter. I saw how to do this with an array, but can't figure it out to do it like this. Any help and explanation would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shuffle the array first (you can also shuffle the answers).  Then enumerate it as you have, inserting shuffled elements into the dom...

```js
let quiz = [
  { lyrics: 'hey jude, whats up with you?',
    answers: [ 'ac/dc', 'the beatles', 'queen' ]
  },
  { lyrics: 'walk like an egyption',
    answers: [ 'guns and roses', 'the bengals', 'bee gees' ]
  },
  { lyrics: 'heard it from a friend who, heard it from a friend who',
    answers: [ 'led zepplin', 'reo speedwagon', 'the eagles' ]
  },
];

let shuffledQuiz = _.shuffle(quiz);
shuffledQuiz.forEach(quizElement => {
      console.log(quizElement.lyrics);
      // insert into your dom here
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You go over the lyrics and take a *random character* from each of them and set it to the DOM, so at the end the page will contain a random char from the last lyric. You want to take a random lyric instead:

```
 var question = document.getElementById("question");
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * musicQuiz.length);
 question.textContent = musicQuiz[random].lyrics;
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the questions listed randomly without repeats.  Seems like a good application for shuffling the musicQuiz array.  underscore.js provides a fisher-yates `_.shuffle()`

Comment: @danh yup probably helpful to the OP, not sure how that is related to my answer ...

Comment: Was suggesting a way your answer could be more helpful to the OP.  I proposed it myself

Answer (score 0):

Split your Lyrics into an array

```
    for (var i = 0; i < musicQuiz.length; i++) 
        {
           var question = document.getElementById("question");
           var lyricsArray = musicQuiz[i].lyrics.split(" ");
           var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * lyricsArray.length);
           question.textContent = lyricsArray[random];
        }
```